# Min Custom formula for monthly expenses spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with this table as an example:

[image]

What I want to do is a formula that displays the lowest value from today until the last day.

Example: If today is the first day, the lowest value (column "Current") until the end of the table is $50 (day 2).

But if today is day 3, for example, I want the cell to display the lowest value from day 3 until the last day, in this case, it would show value $450 at day 4, ignoring all the previous values before day 3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

D4:

```
=MIN(C4:$C$10)
```

Drag fill down

Answer (score 0):

I could find in a forum how to use matrix to calculate:

```
{=MIN(IF(days>=DAY(TODAY());values))}
```

Where days and values are named ranges.